# Laravel cant get controller from route

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-5.4

I have been working on a project and needed to add a feature for resetting a password. I added Laravels build-in feature `php artisan make:auth`, but these controllers in `Controllers/Auth` **don't work** **on this project**.

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [home]
>   not defined.

Maybe unconsciously I have modified something so that it automatically redirects me to `route('home')`, I don't need home route to be rendered, I need it to reach those controllers in Controllers\Auth directory

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

in the App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController change that property as you wish:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: Yes, I see it. But the case is that I cant reach to any page provided by Auth::routes();

Comment: Why does is directs me to Home route, where I try to reach to another page?

Comment: Have you got Auth::routes(); in your routes/web.php file?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I tried that on NEW project. It works on NEW one, but still does not work on the old one  (

Comment: Yeah probably you messed up something, but its difficult to catch without all the code youu wrote. Try to reduce routes and middlewares to the bare minimum until the Auth::routes() work and readd them step by step

Comment: Definitely, I uncommented all my routes. Then it worked fine XD

Comment: Thanks for you cooperations )